# Find all files & directories with group different than owner

Tags: linux, permissions, find, ownership

I want to find all the files and directories that have a group different from the owner.

So if these were the two files in the directory, I'd want to just find the first one:

```
$> ls -l
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user175 group192  866 Dec 12  2006 index.htm
-rw-r--r--. 1 user175 user175   921 Dec 14  2006 index2.html
```

I've been playing with find, but I'm starting to think I'm going to have to give up and write some kind of script (I'd really rather not write a script).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are a **thousands** of directories in Linux. Are you sure you want to do this for **all** directories existing on your machine? Or for specific ones? If the latter, then the task is a lot easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find . -exec sh -c '
      stat -c "%U %G" "$1" |
      awk -F " " "\$1==\$2{exit 1}"
   ' sh {} \; -print
```

It runs `stat` for every object, retrieves its owner and group; `awk` then returns exit status `0` only if they differ. In effect only these are printed.

Notes:

- The performance is low. Each object needs its own separate `sh`, `stat` and `awk`. I had some ideas to improve this (`find . -exec stat … {} + | awk …`) but I'm not sure I can make them robust enough to work with possible filenames with newlines etc. I decided to play it safe. You can use `-print0` if needed. This approach also allows you to add more conditions to `find`.
- In my Kubuntu `stat -c "%U %G"` returns `UNKNOWN` for UIDs (or GIDs) that cannot be translated to names. If there is a user `UNKNOWN` or a group `UNKNOWN`, this will interfere, I think. An object returning `UNKNOWN UNKNOWN` is naively interpreted to have matching owner and group.

Comment: This takes forever even in a directory with few files, but it does seem to work in all cases.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a different solution that uses `ls` and `awk` instead of find. And this certainly needs and can be optimized. Here it goes :

```
ls -alR | awk '{ if ($3 != $4) print $0 }'
```

**How it Works :**

- See what **`-alR`** does from **[man ls](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html)**
- **[awk](https://linux.die.net/man/1/awk)** searches for the pattern.
- **`$3`** & **`$4`** correspondingly gives 3<sup>rd</sup> & 4<sup>th</sup> column in ls output that are `file owner` and `group` that owner is a part of.
- **`$0`** gives complete line in ls output.
- Condition **`if ($3 != $4) print $0`** interprets to *" Print complete line with all columns wherein value in 3<sup>rd</sup> column is not equal to value in 4<sup>th</sup> column "*
- Complete command can be interpreted as **Print only those line in ls output where file owner name and group name is not the same**.

**Limitation :**

Sometimes, It gives this error for some files :

```
ls: cannot open directory './chatscripts': Permission denied
```

As far as I understand, It's a permission issue with the user from which command is being executed. The user is neither owner nor a part of group for that file and thus cannot access it.

---

What you want can be definitely done with `find` command, but I think this can be a solution too and also there still will be this permission issue If you do it with `find` command.

Feel free to add-in more details.

Comment: This seems to work until you hit one of the problem file/directory names as mentioned in "why you shouldn't parse the output of ls".